# Manipulation on vertical space in matplotlib subplots

Tags: matplotlib

I want to reduce the verticalspacing between subplot. Surfing along the web I just have found how to reduce the horizontal spacing, something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4)
fig.tight_layout() # Or equivalently,  "plt.tight_layout()"
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The hspace thing is the one that manipulates such behaviour, but apparently there's no vspace.

EDIT:

This does not reduce the space between the y-axis, that is what I want to manipulate.

Comment: Your code **does** reduce the space between vertical subplots.

Comment: I mean, it does not reduce the space between y-axis in the subplots, that is what I want to do.

Comment: Please read again and do not vote negatively, since the question was misunderstood!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As you said in your question `hspace` reduces the vertical spacing between subplots. The equivalent for horizontal spacing between subplots is `wspace`. Below is an example:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)


fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
fig.tight_layout()
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, y)
ax4.scatter(x, y)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Using a value for 1 for `wspace` gives 
[image]

Using 0.2 as the value of `wspace` gives

[image]

Comment: how counterintuitive to have wspace instead of hspace!

Comment: I suppose `hspace` is _height_ and `wspace` is _width_? But yes, a bit counterintuitive!

Comment: `wspace` and `hspace` force the subplots to get smaller.

Comment: I've found out that `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=..., wspace=...)` works with `fig.tight_layout()`, but silently fails when used with `plt.subplots(..., tight_layout=True)`. (matplotlib 3.5.2).

Answer (score 9):

An alternative approach is to pass the `gridspec_kw` argument a `dict` with keys `wspace` / `hspace`:

#### Example

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.2, 'wspace': 0.9})
plt.tight_layout()

for ax, color in zip(axes.ravel(), list('rgbk')):
    ax.scatter(np.arange(100), np.random.randn(100), color=color)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to reduce the vertical spacing, which is not what I have seen in all of the answers above.

If I am correct, you should reduce the `hspace` from 0.5 to 0.2, for instance. That's because `hspace` does not stand for horizontal spacing, it stands for height spacing, which is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying why you believe the existing answers aren’t relevant, and paraphrasing how you’re interpreting the question. That’s a good practice when answering old questions with established answers.